# Indentation of the second line of a chapter title in the header of a scrbook class document

Tags: header-footer, line-breaking, scrbook

I've got a custom `scrbook` class document and a long chapter title which produces a line break in the printing of the title in the header. The first character of the second line is not aligned with the first character of the first line; instead it is aligned with the chapter number. How can I fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{test}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter[A Bcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwx yz abc defghij klmnopq rs tuv wxyzab cdef Ghijklmnop Qrstuvwx yzabcdefg]{\texorpdfstring{A Bcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwx yz abc defghij klmnopq\newline rs tuv wxyzab cdef Ghijklmnop Qrstuvwx yzabcdefg}{A Bcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwx yz abc defghij klmnopq rs tuv wxyzab cdef Ghijklmnop Qrstuvwx yzabcdefg}}

\newpage
.

\end{document}
```

test.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}

\LoadClass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright, BCOR=1.5cm, appendixprefix, cleardoublepage=empty, numbers=noenddot, bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}

\IfFileExists{scrlayer-scrpage.sty}
{
    \RequirePackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
}{
    \RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
}

\IfFileExists{scrlayer-scrpage.sty}
{
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}

    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \lefoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
    \rofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
    \lehead{\headmark}
    \rohead{\headmark}
}{
    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \lhead[\fancyplain{}{\leftmark}]{}
    \rhead[]{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}
    \lfoot[\fancyplain{\thepage}{\thepage}]{}
    \rfoot[]{\fancyplain{\thepage}{\thepage}}
    \cfoot[]{}

    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    }
}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\textsc{\thechapter~#1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textsl{\thesection~#1}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a short title in header:

```latex
\documentclass[
  %a4paper,% default
  12pt,
  %twoside, openright,% default for scrbook
  BCOR=1.5cm,
  appendixprefix,
  %cleardoublepage=empty,% default
  numbers=noenddot,
  bibliography=totoc,
  headings=optiontoheadandtoc% <- added!
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% only needed with older TeX Distributions
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\ohead{\headmark}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\textsc{\thechapter~#1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textsl{\thesection~#1}}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[
  tocentry={A Bcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwx yz abc defghij klmnopq rs tuv wxyzab cdef Ghijklmnop Qrstuvwx yzabcdefg},
  head={short title for header}
]{A Bcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwx yz abc defghij klmnopq\newline rs tuv wxyzab cdef Ghijklmnop Qrstuvwx yzabcdefg}

\clearpage
.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional remarks:

- Do not load package `inputenc` within a class file. If the package is really needed load it in the document file itself.
- If a KOMA-Script class is available, then package `scrlayer-scrpage` is also installed.

---

If you really need the long version of the chapter title in header:

```latex
\documentclass[
  %a4paper,% default
  12pt,
  %twoside, openright,% default for scrbook
  BCOR=1.5cm,
  appendixprefix,
  %cleardoublepage=empty,% default
  numbers=noenddot,
  bibliography=totoc
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% only needed with older TeX Distributions
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\ohead{\headmark}

\makeatletter% <- added
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\scshape\@hangfrom{\thechapter~}{#1}}{}}% <- changed
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\slshape\@hangfrom{\thesection~}{#1}}}% <- changed
\makeatother% <- added

\usepackage{hyperref}

\KOMAoptions{headlines=2.1}% <-added
\recalctypearea% <- added

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter
  [A Bcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwx yz abc defghij klmnopq rs tuv wxyzab cdef Ghijklmnop Qrstuvwx yzabcdefg]
  {A Bcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwx yz abc defghij klmnopq\newline rs tuv wxyzab cdef Ghijklmnop Qrstuvwx yzabcdefg}

\clearpage
.
\end{document}
```

Note that you have to set a proper value for `headlines` or `headheight` followed by `\recalctypearea` in the preamble of the document.

[image]